# Meaning of limits, $\int_{\max(0, t-5)}^{\max(0,t-3)} e^{-3s} \, ds $?

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

What does it mean to have $\max(0,t-3)$ and $\max(0,t-5)$ in the limits? Is it a abbreviation?
$$
\int_{t-5}^{t-3} e^{-3s}u(s) \, ds = \int_{\max(0, t-5)}^{\max(0,t-3)} e^{-3s} \, ds 
$$

> Source of question:
>
> Calculate the convolution $y(t)=(x\ast h)(t)$ where $x(t)=u(t-3)-u(t-5)$ and $h(t)=e^{-3t}u(t)$.
>   \begin{align}
> y=\cdots &=\int_{t-5}^{t-3} e^{-3s}u(s) \, ds = \int_{\max(0, t-5)}^{\max(0,t-3)} e^{-3s} \, ds \\
> &= \left[-\frac{1}{3}e^{-3s}\right]_{\max(0, t-5)}^{\max(0,t-3)} \\
> &= \frac{1}{3}(e^{-3\max(0,t-5)}-e^{-3\max(0,t-3)})
> \end{align}

Comment: It is not an abbreviation. I means that the upper limit is the $\max$ of $0$ and $t-3$ (whatever $t$ is), and similarly for the lower limit. For example, if $t \le 3$ then the integral will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\max(a,b)$ is simply a function that returns the largest value of $a$ and $b$.

So $\max(0, t-3)$ returns the largest value of $0$ and $t-3$, which is $0$ if $t\leq 3$ and $t-3$ if $t>3$, or put in symbols
$$\max(0,t-3) = \begin{cases} 0&\mbox{if }\, t\leq 3\\
t-3&\mbox{if }\, t > 3\end{cases}. $$